# Parsing Mix data log file

Tags: python, indexing, readfile

I am trying to read a big log file and parse. The log file contains mixed datatypes (example file. log.txt) and extract the min and max value on each category.

**log.txt**

```
header: 
seq: 21925
secs: 1603441909
nsecs: 503731023
data_max: 20.0
data_a: [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 5.611999988555908, 4.644999980926514, 4.689000129699707, 4.7179999351501465, 4.765999794006348, 4.789999961853027, 0.003000000026077032, 0.001000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032]
data_b: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, inf, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 387.0, 341.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 441.0, 300.0, 302.0, 911.0, 320.0, 334.0, 346.0, 354.0, 359.0, 360.0, 397.0, 418.0, 348.0, 344.0, 342.0, 340.0, 334.0, 333.0, 326.0, 323.0, 322.0, 314.0, 305.0, 305.0, 296.0, 290.0, 283.0, 309.0, 284.0, 272.0, 265.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
header: 
seq: 21926
secs: 1603412219
nsecs: 523715525
data_max: 20.0
data_a: [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 12.448999881744385, 4.4770002365112305, 4.513000011444092, 4.546999931335449, 4.571000099182129, 4.61299991607666, 4.64900016784668, 4.690000057220459, 4.711999893188477, 4.763999938964844, 0.003000000026077032, 0.001000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032]
data_b: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 325.0, 321.0, 475.0, 640.0, 375.0, 339.0, 322.0, 309.0, 304.0, 304.0, 382.0, 336.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 307.0, 292.0, 0.0, 321.0, 388.0, 341.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 436.0, 302.0, 303.0, 309.0, 320.0, 338.0, 345.0, 354.0, 361.0, 362.0, 397.0, 415.0, 348.0, 343.0, 340.0, 337.0, 335.0, 333.0, 325.0, 318.0, 317.0, 311.0, 310.0, 985.0, 296.0, 289.0, 281.0, 309.0, 985.0, 268.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Order: seq , secc, nsecs, min value data-a, max value data-a, min value data-b, max value data-b

**output.txt**

```
21925, 1603441909, 503731023,  0.001000000026077032, 5.611999988555908, 0.0, 911.0
21926, 1603412219, 523715525, 0.001000000026077032,  12.448999881744385, 0.0, 985
```

```
def parrse_file():
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as infile: 
            for line in infile:
                chunks = line.split('header:\n')
                for chunk in chunks[1:]:           
                    lines = chunk.strip().splitlines()
                    print lines
```

The problem is I got empty list. What is the root cause? How to parse the lox file and fetch the information exactly like out.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a couple of Python concept. When dealing with a file, looping on a file object is the same as looping on each line.
The below code are equivalent:

```py
with open('log.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

That means, that your line variable will hold, in turn, each line of your file. So when you split on `header` you will never get the expected result.

Let's have a look line by line at your code to understand what's happening:

- ```py
  with open('log.txt', 'r') as infile:
  ```

  You create a context into which infile is a file object of your file `log.txt`
- ```py
      for line in infile:
  ```

  You loop into the file object, this will in fact loop into each line of your
  file, the variable `line`, will take, in turn, the following values:

  - `header:\n`
  - `seq: 21925\n`
  - `secs: 1603441909\n`
  - `nsecs: 503731023\n`
  - `data_max: 20.0\n`
  - ...
- ```py
     chunks = line.split('header:\n')
  ```

  By splitting the line with the string `header:\n` you are constructing a list, based on the value of the variable `line`, `chunks` will look like this:

  - `["header \n"]`
  - `["seq: 21926\n"]`
  - ...
- ```py
  for chunk in chunks[1:]:
  ```

  You are here looping in the `chunks` list starting from the second element (`[1:]`), as `chunks` will always be a list with 1 element, `chunks[1:]` will always be an empty list, thus the code inside the loop is never called.

A possible (and not optimised) implementation of what you want could be:

```py
def parse_file():
    # store each values
    out = []
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as infile:
        # current_section
        current = []
        # loop through each line of the document
        for raw_line in infile.readlines():
            # remove end line
            line = raw_line.strip()
            if line == "header:":
                # if line is header and there is something in current, add to the output
                if len(current) > 0:
                    out.append(" ".join(current))
                # reset current
                current = []
            elif line:
                # get key and val
                line_splitted = line.split(": ")
                key = line_splitted[0]
                val = line_splitted[1]
                # Add to current
                if key in ["seq", "seqs", "nsecs"]:
                    current.append(val)
                elif key in ["data_a", "data_b"]:
                    # Parse list by removing [] and splitting on `, `
                    raw_values = val[1:-1].split(", ")
                    values = []
                    # convert value to float
                    for value in raw_values:
                        if "inf" in value:
                            # skip inf
                            continue
                        values.append(float(value))
                    # Add min max by converting to str
                    current.append(str(min(values)))
                    current.append(str(max(values)))
        # Add last value of current to out
        out.append(" ".join(current))
    return "\n".join(out)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, more importantly for your explanation. Could you please provide more detailed info on my error code? An example will preferable.